# GStreamer iOS - possible streaming & glimagesink blocking issue when returning to corresponding UITabBarController tab

Tags: ios, gstreamer

Running XCode 12.0 beta 6 on a Mac Catalina 10.15.6 connected to an iPhone 8+ 13.5.1
GST Ver: 1.16.1

I've created an app with rtsp video streaming as one of the features from which the stream gets displayed by a GStreamer pipeline on a tab view on a dynamically created UI.
When switching to the streaming tab and starting the stream the first time, it starts, gstreamer & ios are fine & the stream is viewable.
After switching to another tab where the UI Views and window handles go out of focus, I throw away samples coming in from the decoder to an appsink element in the pipeline (described more below).

Switching back to the streaming tab, I resume the stream, and I can tell there is video data coming in (described below), but it is not being displayed.

There are 2 pipelines for the entire stream, separated by appsink and appsrc.
I can tell the video data is coming in after switching back to the tab because the appsink "new-sample" callback I registered is getting called.
Also, in the callback, pushing the samples with gst_app_src_push_sample(...) to the appsrc element returns without error.

Here's an example of what the pipelines look like:

rtspsrc name=rtspsrc01 location=rtsp://192.168.0.25:7768/stream latency=25 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin !  videoconvert ! videobox left=0 right=0 top=0 bottom=0 ! tee name=t2_01 ! queue ! videoscale ! glimagesink name=thumb_sink01  t2_01. ! appsink name=appsink01 sync=false

appsrc name=appsrc01 max-latency=10 ! videoscale ! glimagesink name=viewer_sink01 sync=false

The glimagesink element named "thumb_sink01" is a thumbnail view of the stream displayed on the tab and "appsink01" goes to the "new-sample" callback.
The "appsrc01" element on the second pipeline is receiving the sample from the gst_app_src_push_sample(...) call and goes to a larger UIImageView window on the same tab.

I can see memory consumption growing after switching back to the streaming tab as well, so it appears one of the elements on the second pipeline is blocking for some reason.  I've verified both pipelines are in the state GST_STATE_PLAYING as well.

I've tried quite a few other things such as verifying the views GStreamer is rendering on are valid and even this chunk of code when switching back to the streaming tab and resuming the stream:

```
    gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(self->video_sink), (guintptr) (id)  self->ui_video_view);
    gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(self->thumb_sinks[0]), (guintptr) (id)  self->ui_thumb_views[0]);
    gst_video_overlay_prepare_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(self->thumb_sinks[0]));
    gst_video_overlay_expose(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(self->thumb_sinks[0]));
    gst_video_overlay_prepare_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(self->video_sink));
    gst_video_overlay_expose(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(self->video_sink));
```

I've been assuming that the issue is in the glimagesink element because pushing the sample returns, which indicates to me that appsrc accepted it and no indication of running out of buffers or dropping samples.  I feel unlikely that videoscale would be the culprit either, but I've been wrong before.

Maybe there's something goofy going on with the glimagesink name=thumb_sink01 element.?.? I haven't really looked at that yet.

Appreciate any feedback anyone has.

- Doug

Comment: I realized after monitoring memory consumption in Xcode that it is increasing after switching back to the stream viewing tab and the app crashes after a while when it runs out of memory.  Also, in light of revisiting that OpenGL is deprecated as of iOS 12.0, I'm considering dropping glimagesink and writing the image directly to the window handle myself since it is already a decoded sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My last comment on dropping glimagesink and writing directly to the window handle looks like the way to go, and seems to overall work better.

Taking the raw RGB decoded frame from the appsink sample memory buffer received in the "new-sample" callback and creating a UIImage from that and setting the UIImageView.image to the UIImage works.

Some pseudo code samples to do the conversion if it's useful to others (although plenty of examples are available online):

```
// Create this once before passing any image frames.
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceSRGB);
data->img_ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(img_buff, width, height, 8, width * 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);


// Use this for converting decoded RGB image frames to UIImage's 
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    CGImageRef imgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(data->img_ctx);
    data->the_img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: imgRef];
    CGImageRelease(imgRef);
    [data->ui_video_view setMyImage: (UIImage *)data->the_img];
    [data->ui_video_view setNeedsDisplay];
}); 

// Edit: had problems with subclassing between Objective-C & Swift, so had to create this setter function to work around it.
-(void) setMyImage: (UIImage *) img {
    super.image = img;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for posting this, I don't suppose you'd be willing to share more code or any of the examples you found? Most of the gstreamer resources I've found for iOS or macOS have seemed very outdated and I'd love to get my app off of OpenGL.

Comment: @RoryPrior - I'm afraid our code would do more harm than good.  A lot of trial & error between the objective-c implementation and our Swift codebase.  I'd suggest starting with the GStreamer iOS tutorial here and build on that.  https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/ios/index.html?gi-language=c